# Multi-Threading BS4 scraper does not speed up the process

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I am trying to multithread my scraper so it runs faster. Currently I commented pagination so it finished faster for time measurement but it runs the same as the simple scraper that I did not use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor. Instead it after I try to quit the script from executing using Crtl+c it seems to quit one process, but immediately after quitting ing it seems to continue the same scraper, and I have to stop it from executing again, so something changes, but not the speed, nor the data.

This is my scraper:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import concurrent.futures

NUM_THREADS = 30

BASEURL = 'https://www.motomoto.lt'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(BASEURL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

item_list = []

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS) as executor:
        executor.map(parse_category, soup)


def parse_category(soup):
    for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-name', href=True):
        nexturl = BASEURL + a['href']
        parse_subcategory(nexturl)

def parse_subcategory(url):
    subcategoryPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(subcategoryPage.content, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-image', href=True):
        nexturl= BASEURL + a['href']
        parse_products(nexturl)

def parse_products(url):
    productsPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(productsPage.content, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='thumbnail product-thumbnail', href=True):
        nexturl = a['href']
        parse_item(nexturl)

    # this = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'next'}, href=True)
    # if this is not None:
    #     nextpage = BASEURL + this['href']
    #     print('-' * 70)
    #     parse_products(nextpage)
        
        
def parse_item(url):
    itemPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(itemPage.content, 'html.parser')
    title = get_title(soup)
    price = get_price(soup)
    category = get_category(soup)
    
    item = {
        'Title': title,
        'Price': price,
        'Category': category
    }

    item_list.append(item)
    print(item)
    
def get_title(soup):
    title = soup.find('h1', class_='h1')
    title_value = title.string
    title_string = title_value.strip()
    return title_string

def get_price(soup):
    price = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'price'}).string.strip()
    return price

def get_category(soup):
    category = soup.find_all("li", attrs={'itemprop':'itemListElement'})[1].find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).getText()
    return category

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently I am multithreading the first function, that uses the BS4 soup to gather the category links. How may I fix it to make it faster, even though it's using multiple functions?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of ThreadPoolExecutor.[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) is

```py
map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)
```

The executor processes `iterables` concurrently.
If you have supplied multiple `soup`s like `executor.map(parse_category, [soup1, soup2, ...])` they will be processed in parallel. But since you have supplied only one `soup`, you are "doing one thing concurrently", which means there is no concurrency.

As you are calling `parse_category` only once, it worse not adding concurrency to it. Instead, you can parallelize `parse_subcategory` and `parse_products` like this:

```py
...

def main():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS)
    parse_category(soup, executor)

def parse_category(soup, executor):
    executor.map(
        lambda url: parse_subcategory(url, executor),
        [BASEURL + a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-name', href=True)])


def parse_subcategory(url, executor):
    subcategoryPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(subcategoryPage.content, 'html.parser')
    executor.map(
        lambda url: parse_products(url, executor),
        [BASEURL + a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-image', href=True)])
        

def parse_products(url, executor):
    productsPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(productsPage.content, 'html.parser')
    executor.map(
        parse_item,
        # here you missed the `BASEURL`, I kept it as-is
        [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='thumbnail product-thumbnail', href=True)])
...
```

The remainder of the script is unchanged.

I didn't test it as the website seems inaccessible from my location. Reply if there's any bug.

Comment: I have tried writing exactly like you and also pasting the same snippet to my code but it does not seem to run. After launching the script it quits instantly without any errors in the terminal. In parse_products, why do we not need do have a 'lambda url: parse_item(url, executor) and only write 'parse_item' instead?

Comment: `executor` is needed in some functions because we need to call `executor.map()` from the function. In `parse_item` we don't.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake. Corrected. You only need to remove the asterisks. Details: The second parameter to `executor.map()` was `iterables` and I treated it as `items`.

Comment: The parse_products function is not being called, as if the executor is no longer valid, could it be that the ThreadPoolExecutor() is closed?

Comment: There's no more executor in the parse_subcategory, as it is closed or never passed. Digging deeper.

Comment: I started new ThreadPoolExecutors in other scripts, only then it starts to parse items, but I am not sure if that's really the way it should work.

Comment: The executor will be scheduled for shutting down whenever the code leaves the `with` scope. Existing jobs will still be run but new jobs cannot be submitted. Since there's no easy way to figure out when will all jobs be completed, maybe we can replace the `with ` clause with `executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)`. The terminal will wait until the last thread is exited then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244180/discussion-between-meow-cat-2012-and-dovexz12323).